# Are mercurial paths expanded recursively in hgrc?

Tags: configuration, mercurial

In mercurial, you add lines to hgrc in the [paths] section to create aliases to push to and pull from. But can these be expanded recursively? For example:

```
# .hg/hgrc
[paths]
myserver = ssh://myserver/path/to/remote/repo
default = myserver
```

If I put that in my hgrc and try to do `hg push default`, will it push to myserver?

Comment: I did try after posting the question, but I figured it would be good to have the answer on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not. A simple test with the following hgrc file:

```
[paths]
repo = C:\Temp\repo
default = repo
```

and then a push:

```
[C:\Temp\clone1] :hg push
abort: repository C:\Temp\clone1\repo not found!
```

... tells me that this doesn't work. You're going to have to copy the URL's.

Basically, it looks like the name is just understood as a local, relative path, from where the current repository resides.